# Как сделать так, чтобы персонаж всегда отрисовывался по центру экрана?

Tags: c#, winforms, разработка-игр

Создаю платформер на чистом C#. Хочу чтобы игрок всегда отрисовывался в центе экрана, однако никак не могу понять как это сделать. Необходимо хотя бы понять, как изначально централизовать камеру.

Comment: а что ты подразумеваешь под игроком и под камерой?

Comment: @Pekor ну игрок, это некий объект, который отрисовывается на экране, а камера - тот объект, который содержит в себе координаты сдвига отрисовки относительно игрока. То есть если игрок двигается влево, то и все объекты "сдвигаются влево"

Comment: `Хочу чтобы игрок всегда отрисовывался в центе экрана, однако никак не могу понять как это сделать` - ну видимо вызывать функцию отрисовки в которой рассчитывается ширина и высота окна (формы) и делить их на 2, в этих координатах отрисовывать персонажа

Comment: Просто не меняйте координаты персонажа. Двигайте игровое поле. ЗЫ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1276543/184217